# How do I get the min and max of a set of rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

With a MySQL database table in the following style:

```
A  B  C  D
-------------   
a, b, c, 1990
a, b, c, 1991
a, b, c, 1992
a, d, f, 1990
a, d, f, 1991
a, d, f, 1992
e, g, h, 1990
e, g, h, 1991
```

Is there a simple or SQL way to get it to form

```
a, b, c, 1990, 1992
a, d, f, 1990, 1992
e, g, h, 1990, 1991
```

?

Currently I can only think of fetching the unique letter combinations, foreach  unique combination checking the min and max years, and inserting rows to a new table. The current table is in use in a legacy module I'm not willing to touch at this time.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What is the name of the table and what are the names of the columns?

Comment: Does the column order matter? I.e. do you consider (a, b, c) to be distinct from (c, b, a)?

Comment: column order matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select A, B, C, max(D) as max_col, min(D) as min_col
from table
group by A, B, C
order by A,B,C
```

Answer (score 2):

Just aggregate over the three columns and take the min/max:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, col3, MIN(year) AS min_year, MAX(year) AS max_year
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    col1, col2, col3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     select letter1,
            letter2,
            letter3,
            min(year),
            max(year) 
       from table 
   group by letter1,
            letter2,
            letter3 
   order by letter1,
            letter2,
            letter3
```

Comment: @Esa That depends on your RDBMS and whether or not you have indices defined. If this is a large table, having an index on (letter1,letter2,letter3) would be a brilliant idea. Adding year as well to the index might be even better. Note that in the latter case the index and the table is identical, depending on your RDBMS you can then use some special table/index type.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
select A, B, C, max(D), min(D) 
into #temp
from tablename
group by A, B, C
```